# Can I access Hadoop files in Java without using MapReduce?

Tags: java, hadoop

Is a MapReduce structure mandatory to program in Hadoop or can we can just run any type of simple JAR also?

I am trying to access files in HDFS from Java code. I tried:

```
static{
    URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory());    
}

in = new URL("hdfs://cluster-server:54310/home/hduser/sort/inputs").openStream();
IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 2, false);
```

But when I run this code from Eclipse it results in an error:

> Call to cluster-server/172.16.18.75:54310 failed on local exception: null

But I can see that the files exist in the Hadoop HDFS cluster through the command line interface.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to just run a Jar with Hadoop?

Answer (score 2):

In the current version of Hadoop - MapReduce is only paradigm supported. In the next version it will become libraray and other paradigms of parallel processing would be supported. 
Today you can run any jar via hadoop command - but it will simply run Your main locally. 
Yes, you can access HDFS without any connection to MapReduce, but you should do it via Hadoop classes - not general java IO.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the OP just wants to access HDFS programmatically from a Java program. If that is the case, I found this link to be very useful:- http://blog.rajeevsharma.in/2009/06/using-hdfs-in-java-0200.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access files in HDFS, chapter 3 in **Hadoop: The Definitive Guide** is a good start. Using URL to open input stream may not work for HDFS.

Comment: A suggestion: You may assert that "in != null" to make sure you can use URL to open input stream when using HDFS.